# passing large arrays via link_to function (or by other means) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-post, link-to

I know that link_to uses get action by default and also you can change the method to post by passing :method => :post to link_to function, but it does not seem to work.  Here is the syntax that I am using:

= link_to "Export" export_path(:data_array => d_array), :method => 'post'

But this does not seem to work.  The array is being passed by as a query parameter which I can see in the URL box and it bombs my application since it blows the string length limit in the url string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using form instead:

```
= form_tag export_path do
  - d_array.each do |val|
    = hidden_field_tag 'data_array[]', val
  = submit_tag 'Export'
```

Notice that in a controller `params[:data_array]` will be an array of strings.

Comment: I am not sure if that is the answer for the following reasons: 1.  I need to have many such export links on this page and as I understand it, one html doc cannot have multiple "form" html elements. 2. the data array is really a complex array (or an array of arrays), so I want to pass it as one blob, if I don't then I have to recompute it in the controller function.

Comment: @Bharat 1. Why not? Just make sure that your forms aren't nested.
2. There's nothing to do with it. Either you pass query as whole string and encounter same trouble, either you have to parse your params.